# rdmd Command Not Recognized

Tags: compilation, d

I am a first-timer at D, so maybe I am missing something obvious here.  I am trying to compile some D code using the `rdmd` command.

```
$ rdmd dfile.d input.txt
No command 'rdmd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'wdmd' from package 'sanlock' (universe)
 Command 'rdsd' from package 'rdsserver' (universe)
 Command 'gdmd' from package 'gdc' (universe)
rdmd: command not found
```

Is there something I need to install before my D code will compile? There is very limited resources on the internet for D.  I apologize for such a weak question, but I am a bit stuck!

I am using Linux Mint 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something I need to install before my D code will compile?

Yes, you need to install a D compiler - see [here](http://dlang.org/download.html) for a list of downloads.

> There is very limited resources on the internet for D.

Try searching for "Dlang" or "D programming" if your search results appear irrelevant.

Comment: Foolish me.  I have been using your referred site, but never came across the download.  Thanks!